# Change type of Name field on Custom Object

Tags: data-model

If I set up a Custom Object with an Autonumber type name field, is there a way to refactor it to a Text field without deleting the Custom Object, recreating it, and then re-loading any backed-up data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried editing the Name field and changing it's 'Data Type' to text?

Comment: There's no option to change data type displayed for the special Name field (or at least, I can't see one if it's there).

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something then.  I see something like the following:  http://i.imgur.com/a33Wd.png

Comment: D'oh!  Yeah, I was totally missing that.

Comment: Note that this isn't a valid option for objects from a managed package. In that case there's sadly no way to do this.

Comment: Though at this point this is a very old post, I wanted to mention that *technically* you can make this change even for a managed package.

In Chrome dev tools you can insert the HTML for the picklist shown in non-managed orgs in lieu of the uneditable text shown in your managed org and then save as demonstrated here: http://screencast.com/t/5Rehk0v3Q

NOTE: This is obviously a hack and not supported/recommended by Salesforce-always beware of making changes like this to a managed package. It's quite likely you'll block existing customers from being able to upgrade by doing this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to go to object and then click on Edit in front of Name field under standard fields section. Am able to change the Autonumber to text and then Text to Autonumber again and again. Please let me know if you are not able to change it.

Comment: a note on going text -> autonumber it doesn't actually change the text of any existing records TO an autonumber. Only new records going forward